# jQuery: how to style a concatenated element inside a div separately from rest of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the `email` variable dynamically added inside the successEmailView variable which is appended later one.  However, I want to style the `email` text so that it's a different color.  How can I do this since it becomes part of the success-container div?

```
  let email = $('#email').val()
  let successEmailView = '<div class="success-container"><div class="text-success">An email was sent to ' + email + ' with instructions for resetting your password</div>
```

Comment: Are you using SMTP to send email?

Comment: this is not email related -- only client side html/jquery/css..I'm just using the variable email to get the value of the user's email address

Comment: Ok. Please try $(email)  in your statement you wrote above

Comment: Or wrap whole statement of successEmailView in $(),  Hope this may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it on span like so:

```
  let email = $('#email').val()
  let successEmailView = '<div class="success-container"><div class="text-success">An email was sent to <span class="myemail">' + email + '</span> with instructions for resetting your password</div>
```

Then target the class `.myemail` and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your need correctly, try this:

```
 let email = $('#email').val()
 let successEmailView = '<div class="success-container"><div class="text-success">An email was sent to ' + 
     '<span>'+email +'</span>'+
      ' with instructions for resetting your password</div>
```

Now the css:

```
.text-success>span{
     color: #f90 !important;
}
```

Or in the html itself (inline style):

```
 ... +'<span style="color: #f90 !important;">'+email +'</span>'+...
```

And if you need changing the color after appending it:

```
 var r=/ [a-z][a-z0-9_.]*?@[a-z][a-z0-9_]*?\.[a-z]{1,4} /i;//This is not a good RegExp for email and I just wrote it for your tests. You can find proper one with a search
 var dst=document.querySelector(".text-success");
 dst.innerHTML=dst.innerHTML.replace(r, function(em){return "<span>"+em+"</span>";});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not implement style simply on text. You have to have some wrapper element around the text. You can wrap the value with `span` with a class and add style you want to the class:

```js
let email = $('#email').val();
email = '<span class="emailText">' + email + '</span>';

let successEmailView = '<div class="success-container"><div class="text-success">An email was sent to ' + email + ' with instructions for resetting your password</div>';

$('body').append(successEmailView);
```

```css
.emailText { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email" value="Sample Text"/>
```